# Wget Macro for downloading multiple URLS?

Tags: linux, download, macros, wget

*(NOTE: You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links. I had to remove the http and urls, but it's still understandable i hope!)*

Hello!

I am trying to Wget an entire website for personal educational use. Here's what the URL looks like:

**example.com/download.php?id=1**

i want to download all the pages from 1 to the last page which is 4952

so the first URL is:

**example.com/download.php?id=1**

and the second is

**example.com/download.php?id=4952**

What would be the most efficient method to download the pages from 1 - 4952?

My current command is (it's working perfectly fine, the exact way i want it to):

```
wget -P /home/user/wget -S -nd --reject=.rar http://example.com/download.php?id=1
```

**NOTE: The website has a troll and if you try to run the following command:**

```
 wget -P /home/user/wget -S -nd --reject=.rar --recursive --no-clobber --domains=example.com --no-parent http://example.com/download.php
```

**it will download a 1000GB .rar file just to troll you!!!**

Im new to linux, please be nice! just trying to learn!

Thank you!

Comment: Use `for i in {1..4952}` and then insert `$i` into the URL.

Comment: Resolving {1..4952} ({1..4952})... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘{1..4952}’

Comment: What shell are you using for the script? `{1..4952}` works in `bash`.

Comment: What do you mean by "macro"? Do you mean shell script?

Comment: no i just used macro as a general term, im using Terminal, If it helps im using Tails if it helps. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know what Tails is. What is your default shell? Use `echo $SHELL` to see it.

Comment: user@tails:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: Post your solution as an answer.

Comment: never mind, i ran into an issue, so to get past the troll, i simply blocked the 1000gb.rar/.zip file in my hosts file, however, it successfully downloaded the first 20 files, but then continued to download, but instead of downloading the http://example.com/download.php?id=1 it moved on to downloading the next page as an .php file, instead of downloading the files individually its now downloading just the php file

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be trying to download so many pages from site that doesn't want you to. Contact the site administrator and find out if there's a way for you to get the data without bombarding them with thousands of requests.

Comment: i have permission from the user, it's just for fun, im trying to learn how to wget properly. he has setup parameters to mess with me.

Comment: Try pausing between each download.

Comment: tried that, same issue, your original answer should work, i just have no idea how to make it work. :(

Comment: I don't know what a troll is, but I'm guessing his server notices when the same client tries to download lots of pages, and after several requests it sends the big file. You need to find out what the criteria is, and then work around it. No one here knows what he's doing, so it's not something we can help with.

Comment: Ah, I will keep researching and update periodically :)

Comment: This question is not likely to be useful to the site. It's not a general problem that other programmers would have, it's a puzzle that your friend has set up for you to solve.

Comment: It might come in hand for users who want to wget a website that has built in firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

Notepadd++ =

your URL + Column Editor = Massive list of all urls

Wget -I your_file_with_all_urls = Success!

thanks to Barmar